# git reset --soft to save face with big files

Tags: git, github, git-reset

So I accidentally pushed some big files to Github on master branch.

After I did that, I tried doing:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
```

then I removed the big files, committed, then tried pushing to the remote master, but I get an error saying my local branch is missing commits from the remote master branch.

What should I do? Was there something I should have done instead other than using `git reset --soft`?

Comment: *"my local branch is missing commits from the remote master branch"* - is that surprising? You removed two commits by resetting behind them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: How to rewrite a remote history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009568/git-how-to-rewrite-a-remote-history)

Comment: @jonrsharpe not surprising at all, but the local branch is tracking the remote. They were in sync until I did the reset. Maybe you could answer the question?

Comment: You've got the answer: you have to force push if you want to change the history.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok, but was there a better way to do that other than `git reset --soft`...did I really have to add "what should I have done instead?" to the OP to get an answer that included "what I should have done instead"?

Comment: What do you mean *"better"*? It's unclear what your criteria are or what outcomes would have been acceptable. For example, does it particularly matter if the offending commits still appear in the history? Do you have some unstated requirement that prevents you from force pushing?

Comment: I need to get rid of the accidentally committed large files both locally and on the remote for the branch.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that `git push --force` might be needed after you remove the file from the repo history following [the "Removing sensitive data from a repository" guide](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/).